# Getting Error 401 from Reddit API

Tags: c#, api, unity-game-engine, token, reddit

Trying to get an access token from the reddit api. This code: https://codeshare.io/5OdLWr should work,  but it gives Error 401 unauthorized. The text is json for the error 401. Here are screenshots of the console and coroutine path that helped me: 
`https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/283268638683693066/288041834754605056/path.png`

`https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/283268638683693066/288039624943599616/unknown.png`

I have tried very hard to fix this but sometimes you just need another mind to see your problem.

Comment: That code is using Basic authentication - are you sure your username/password is correct? They appear to be read in from a text-file in the code you supplied.

Comment: Do you know how the API works? The text file I'm reading has nothing to do with the username and password. In fact, I'm not even logging in. I'm using the basic token request. Read https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/OAuth2 Application Only OAuth if you don't know.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood the code - I read lines 34-38 as creating a Basic authentication header, so made an assumption.

Comment: It's ok, just doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: When possible, questions should be [self-contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339450/should-code-from-pastebin-be-edited-into-a-question). Links to external "pastebins" are prone to breaking, which doesn't serve future visitors very well.